# XA RECOVER: how to convert unreadable xid

Tags: mysql, transactions

I want to execute the mysql-command on my MySQL 5.6 Server:

```
mysql> XA ROLLBACK xid;
```

I tried to get the xid from this command:

```
mysql> XA RECOVER;
```

the result looks as this:
[image]

My question for the community is:
How do I get the xid in an readable format which I can insert in the "XA ROLLBACK xid" command?
Is there a way to convert it?

Regards
Tom

Answer (score 1):

You can use XA RECOVER CONVERT XID;

it will give you can xid in hexadecimal value, you can convert it to XA COMMIT format and execute it .

Comment: As stated I'm on MySQL 5.6 Server. As far as I know this is not possible with 5.6.